# Launch Activity from another Application Android

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android Launch an application from another application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872063/android-launch-an-application-from-another-application)

I am having a problem and it is the following one:

I have two applications, and I want to launch one of the activities from one app by the other one......I am gonna give an example:

first app package:

> "es.wul4.android.app1"

second app package:

> "es.wul4.android.app2"

What I want is to launch the activity whose class is called `"Identificar"` from the app1

This activity is NOT the main one. I tried by doind that:

```
Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("es.wul4.app2.Identificar");
startActivity(intent);
```

But what i get doing that is nothing, it tells me that the app doesn´t exists.

If i try doing that:

```
getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("es.wul4.app2");
startActivity(intent);
```

And it launch one activity, but the main one........

How can I launch this particular Activity inside the package "es.wul4.app2.Identificar"??

Thank u very much.

Comment: You want to start particular activity?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

What you need to use are `intent-filters`. Assume the activity to be launched is in the package `launch.me`. Inside this applications manifest all the activities (main or otherwise) will be decalred by the `<activity>` tag.
Assuming the activity you want to launch is inside the class file `Launchme`. Then a portion of your manifest will be something like:

```
<activity android:name="launch.me.Launchme"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="launch.me.action.LAUNCH_IT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
</intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Now in the activity from where you want to launch the above activity use:(Note: This activity can be in any package anywhere. You have to make sure that both, the calling and the called packages are available on the device)

```
Intent i=new Intent();
i.setAction("launch.me.action.LAUNCH_IT");
startActivityForResult(i,0);
```

You can use other methods for starting the intent other than `startActivityForResult`, thats upto you.

Comment: Thank you! I didn´t know it was neccesary to use the <intent-filter> to launch the activity, now I can launch the activity without any problems and I even can send determinated data

Comment: yes, you can easily pass values in between them by using `putExtra` with the intents :)

Answer (score 1):

Did you add activity inside `app1`s manifest?:

```
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".Identificar" >
    </activity>
```

Comment: +1 for important thing is mentioned

Comment: .......I think you didn´t understand very well....app1 doesn´t contain Activity Identificar. The Activity Identificar is inside app2. What I want is to launch this activity from the app1. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score -4):

I think, since both activities are in the same package that you only have to do:

```
startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Identificar.class));
```

Comment: read question again ... "first app package: `es.wul4.android.app1`, second app package: `es.wul4.android.app2`"