# Passing data from one app to another one

Tags: android, android-intent

I have 2 android apps:

```
app1 - Activity11 --> Activity12 --> Activity13

app2 - Activity21 --> Activity22 --> Activity23
```

I want to pass from one app to **the second** Activity of the other one, **passing some datas**.

```
app1 - Activity11 -->(switch to app2)--> Activity22 --> Activity23
```

What steps have i to follow? Do you know some tutorial?

I haven't write code for now, because I don't know where to start.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10960709/android-call-activity-of-another-application) one might help you too.

Comment: Thanks. I missed these! The first one seems helpful.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to look into android Intents and Intent Filters. [Check this training article for example](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html).

[This blog post can also be an interesting read](http://android-developers.blogspot.be/2012/02/share-with-intents.html).

A quick example for sending text (other types are in the links on top);

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

And for receiving:

```
void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    // Get intent, action and MIME type
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String action = intent.getAction();
    String type = intent.getType();

    if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) && type != null) {
        if ("text/plain".equals(type)) {
            handleSendText(intent); // Handle text being sent
        } else if (type.startsWith("image/")) {
            handleSendImage(intent); // Handle single image being sent
        }
    } else if (Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE.equals(action) && type != null) {
        if (type.startsWith("image/")) {
            handleSendMultipleImages(intent); // Handle multiple images being sent
        }
    } else {
        // Handle other intents, such as being started from the home screen
    }
    ...
}

void handleSendText(Intent intent) {
    String sharedText = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
    if (sharedText != null) {
        // Update UI to reflect text being shared
    }
}

void handleSendImage(Intent intent) {
    Uri imageUri = (Uri) intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
    if (imageUri != null) {
        // Update UI to reflect image being shared
    }
}

void handleSendMultipleImages(Intent intent) {
    ArrayList<Uri> imageUris = intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
    if (imageUris != null) {
        // Update UI to reflect multiple images being shared
    }
}
```

You'll have to update the manifest also:

```
<activity android:name=".ui.MyActivity" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: Thanks. This seems to be a good starting point.