# Null Pointer exception and intent error

Tags: java, android, android-intent, nullpointerexception, android-checkbox

My App Always crash whenever I click on a button... the button gets text from an `edittext`, and i believe that that is why i have a `null pointer exception`. First question: how can i check if the `editText` is empty? I already tried `.equals("")`, `.equals(null)`, same with matches, and `.lenght == 0`
Second, when i try to call the intent for my `listActivity` class i get a handling error. (Activity not found. No activity to handle.)
Ill give you my onClickListener

**ON CLICK LISTENER**

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                searchInEnglish = rSearchEnglish.isChecked();
                searchInDovahzul = rSearchDovahzul.isChecked();

                searchBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tvSearch);

                if (searchBox.getText().toString().equals("")){

                    if (searchInEnglish) {
                        int counter = 0;
                        for (int i = 0; i < englishArray.length; i++) {
                            if (englishArray[i].contains(searchBox.getText())) {
                                counter++;
                                Intent search = new Intent(
                                        "net.fernandezgodinho.pedro.dovahzuldictionary.SEARCHLIST");
                                startActivity(search);
                            }
                        }
                        setFinalSearch(searchResultsEnglish);
                    }

                    if (searchInDovahzul = true) {
                        int counter = 0;
                        for (int i = 0; i < dovahzulArray.length; i++) {
                            if (dovahzulArray[i].contains(searchBox.getText())) {
                                counter++;
                                Intent search = new Intent(
                                        "net.fernandezgodinho.pedro.dovahzuldictionary.SEARCHLIST");
                                startActivity(search);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please use at least two characters", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Try to start your activity like `Intent search = new Intent(
                                    CurrentActivity.this, NewActivity.class);`
                            `startActivity(search);` and see if error persist.

Comment: paste your logcat stacktrace

Comment: Did you add the intent to the intent-filter of the corresponding activity?

Comment: OH i forgot to add the intent-filter to the manifest... Sorry for the error, im a begginer on android. Thanks a lot for your help everyone. Now ill just correct the if statement block, and them, teoricly, it should work. Thanks everyone for your help again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are calling an activity from another application.

Have you added the `<intent-filter>` to another activity in the application manifest ?

Step #1: Add an `<intent-filter>` to the second activity with a custom action:

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="com.testapp.ws.XYZ"/>
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

Step #2: Start that activity using an appropriate Intent:

```
startActivity(new Intent("com.testapp.ws.XYZ"));
```

See this for further explanations - https://stackoverflow.com/a/10961409/826657

Comment: ill try this out, but its not from another app... its same app, same package

Comment: I was calling from the same app, but i forgot to add to the manifest and wasted all day on this, but luckly you remembered :) thanks

Comment: o no probs ! happy to help !

Answer (score 1):

To check EditText is null or not, write below code

```
EditText editText=(EditText)findviewById(R.id.myEditText);

if(TextUtils.isEmpty(editText.getText())){

     // show msg or whatever you want to do on empty text case    

}else{

}
```