# Sending bundle with Explicit Intents

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to send and Intent from my library project to my working project (that has that library attached with it.). Here I am calling my activity from my library project like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("isr.LAUNCH");
                intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.abc.def", "com.abc.def.screens.BaseActivity_New"));
                intent.putExtra("selectedbook_id",MyReader.BOOK_ID );
                intent.putExtra("isReaderSample", MyReader.IS_SAMPLE);
                intent.putExtra("landing_fragment", "reader_backtrack");
                MyReader.activity.startActivity(intent);
                MyReader.activity.finish();
```

This is how I am extracting bundle in BaseActivity_New:

```
bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
```

Activity, is fired correctly, but bundle is always null when I check it in the OnResume of the BaseActivity_New and **my launch mode of BaseActivity is singleInstance**

Can anyone please help me how to send bundle with Explicit Intents.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As its is singleInstance I just see you edit the answer.

Override this method

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    setIntent(intent);
    //now getIntent() should always return the last received intent
}
```

Comment: Thanks Biraj Zalavadia

Answer (score 0):

Getting data with:

> String mBookId = getIntent().getStringExtra("selectedbook_id");