# Call activity by another application

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

So guys, I have 2 app and I want call the activity of one by other.. 
I looked for on Google and I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10960709/android-call-activity-of-another-application) but when I execute this:

```
No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.messaging.LaunchM (has extras) }
   at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1856)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1552)
```

This is my code

App 1

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.messaging.LaunchM");
intent.putExtra(Constants.TEST, "test");
fragmentActivity.startActivity(intent);
```

App 2

```
<activity
    android:name=".activities.HomeFragmentActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
    android:label="@string/appName">

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.messaging.LaunchM" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: The second answer is a better approach IMHO https://stackoverflow.com/a/10960743/603270

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10960709/android-call-activity-of-another-application