# What Intent Filter is to be added to allow External App to get data from our App

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest

I want to make App which is invoked by external App, and allowing it to get some string values in result. I am able to invoke my App, but unable to pass data. So I think something within intent filter is to be modified. Correct me if I am going on wrong track. What value is to be taken for **action** & **category** or any other thing from manifest.

```
    <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
```

Further description @ [StartActivity for Result for external App not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34488029/5602596)

Answer (score 0):

> I am able to invoke my App, but unable to pass data

If the caller uses `startActivityForResult()`, you can use `setResult()` and `finish()` at the appropriate point to set the result (in the form of an `Intent`) and return control to the original activity. For example, if you are presenting a list of items to the user, when the user taps on an item, you can create an `Intent` with details about the item (e.g., as string extras), pass that `Intent` to `setResult()`, and then call `finish()`.

> So I think something within intent filter is to be modified.

`<intent-filter>` elements have nothing technically to do with supplying a result.

Comment: I have done the same you can see it here - http://stackoverflow.com/q/34488029/5602596 But I am getting ResultCode=0 at the moment Activity is invoked

Comment: @14mcei: I am not surprised. Get rid of `SecondActivity`, or merge its functionality into `MainActivity`. `startActivityForResult()` does not handle well the case when the started activity turns around and starts other activities.

Comment: Suppose I move task of SecondActivity into MainActivity by creating Fragments, will it do ?

Comment: @14mcei: Presumably that will be OK. To be honest, I think that your use of `startActivityForResult()` here is inappropriate. `startActivityForResult()` is really for fairly simple situations, where the activity being started has to present a simple choice to users (e.g., pick a file, pick an activity) and return that to the caller. If the activity being started is complex enough to warrant multiple fragments (let alone downstream activities), I would not use `startActivityForResult()`, but instead fix the overall app architecture.