# Send Data From One App to A Specific Activity in Another App

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I want to send data from one app to a specific activity in another app.

The code below sends data to the main activity in another app. But I want to **specify an activity** within `IntentReceiver`.

**IntentSender**

```
Intent intent = this.ApplicationContext.PackageManager.GetLaunchIntentForPackage("com.IntentReceiver");
intent.PutExtra("Message", "Hello");
StartActivity(intent);
```

**IntentReceiver**

```
var message = Intent.GetStringExtra("Message");
Toast.MakeText(this, $"OnResume {message}", ToastLength.Long).Show();
```

Below is for android, but I have problem implementing it in `Xamarin Android`.

[Android : Call activity of another application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10960709/android-call-activity-of-another-application)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first app, you can need the following code to open the specific activity in second app.

```
            Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.SEND");
            //this first parameter is pageckage name of secound app,the secound parameter is specific activiy name totally

            ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName("reciverApp.reciverApp", "reciverApp.reciverApp.Activity1");
            intent.SetComponent(componentName);
            intent.PutExtra("Message", "Hello");
            StartActivity(intent);
```

In the second app, open the specific activity. Add annotation，you should add `Exported = true` `Name = "reciverApp.reciverApp.Activity1"` `IntentFilter`

```
    [Activity(Label = "Activity1",Exported = true,Name = "reciverApp.reciverApp.Activity1")   ]
[IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionSend }, Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryDefault })]
public class Activity1 : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.layout1);


    }
    protected override void OnResume()
    {

        var message = Intent.GetStringExtra("Message");
        if (message != null)
        {

            Toast.MakeText(this, $"OnResume {message}", ToastLength.Long).Show();
        }
        base.OnResume();

    }
```

There is a GIF of my running demo.
[image]

There is code of my demo. You should run the reciverApp firstly, then run the sendApp 
https://github.com/851265601/OpenAnotherActvityDemo

If you have some doubts about this circumstances, there is a simple article about sending simple data to other apps.

https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send

This scenario contains Intent/Intentfilter, If you want to know more details about it, this link is helpful.
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters#PendingIntent

Comment: Can you provide links to IntentFilter, Intent.ActionSend, ComponentName, Categories? for the completeness of an answer.

Comment: Are users with MSFT ending from Microsoft?

Comment: @Pingpong I have update my answer, hope it helpful to you.MSFT is on behalf of Microsoft, not all MSFT is from Microsoft.

Comment: Do you have any updates? If the reply help to you, please mark the reply as answer.

Comment: If you have some questions about it, you could post it here, if not, please mark it as answer, it is very important for us.

Comment: Do you know how to send data to other app, but I don't want to lauch its activity?