# React Native intents interaction (onActivityResults running before an activity starts)

Tags: android, react-native, android-intent

I need help or guidance in resolving the issue that I have regarding React Native interacting with other native applications via intents. I know that React Native supports deeplinking out of the box but does not cater for intents, which means that one needs to create an android native module ([https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bxwyu.png)). I created a native module that calls 3rd party applications via intents and passing data using **startActivityForResults** and created **onActivityResult** that is supposed to handle data returned from 3rd party applications after closing. However, the **onActivityResult** executes prematurely before external applications open.

Starting the activity using **startActivityForResults**:

```
    @ReactMethod
    public void launchApp(String stringArgument, ReadableMap args, Promise promise) throws JSONException{

        try {
            final JSONObject options = convertMapToJson(args);
            Bundle extras = new Bundle();;
            int LAUNCH_REQUEST = 0;

            if (options.has("extras")) {
                extras = createExtras(options.getJSONArray("extras"));
                Log.d(TAG,"Extras found");
                Log.d(TAG, options.getString("extras"));
            } else {
                extras = new Bundle();
                Log.d(TAG,"No extras");
            }

            if (options.has("launchRequestCode")) {
                LAUNCH_REQUEST = options.getInt("launchRequestCode");
            }

            Intent packageIntent = this.reactContext.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(stringArgument);
            if(packageIntent != null){
                packageIntent.putExtras(extras);
                //callback.invoke("Starting activity for: "+stringArgument);
                Activity activity = getReactApplicationContext().getCurrentActivity();
                //this.reactContext.startActivityForResult(packageIntent, LAUNCH_REQUEST, extras);
                activity.startActivityForResult(packageIntent, LAUNCH_REQUEST);
                return;
                //mPromise.put(LAUNCH_REQUEST, promise);
            }
            else{
                Log.d(TAG, stringArgument+" package not found");
                //callback.invoke("Package not found: "+stringArgument);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            //TODO: handle exception
            Log.d(TAG, e.toString());
        }
        // TODO: Implement some actually useful functionality
        
    }
```

Expecting the data back using **onActivityResults**

```
ActivityEventListener mActivityEventListener = new ActivityEventListener(){

        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(Activity activity, int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            //super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resCode, data);
    
            Log.d(TAG,"On activity result");
           
            if (mPromise != null && resultCode == activity.RESULT_OK) {
                WritableMap result = new WritableNativeMap();
                result.putInt("resultCode", resultCode);
                result.putMap("data", Arguments.makeNativeMap(data.getExtras()));
                mPromise.resolve(result);
            }
            else{
                Log.d(TAG,"Promise and intent data are empty");
                //mPromise.reject("Unable to get promise or intent data is empty");
            }

            if(resultCode == activity.RESULT_CANCELED ){
                Log.d(TAG,"Result cancelled or no result or crashed with code");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNewIntent(Intent intent){
            Log.d(TAG,"New Intent");
        }

    };
```

Android Manifest file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.navapp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
      <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

By using Android Studio Logcat to debug, I found out that the onActivityResults executes immediately before the external app opens up.
[Logcat screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bxwyu.png)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to this explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10960709/android-call-activity-of-another-application), I was able to drill down to what was causing the issue. In my React Native application, I used the package name of the external application instead of the action name to open it.

**Manifest File of the external app:**

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.bld.pushnotification.Main"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

I also modified the my code for launching the app:

```
@ReactMethod
public void launchApp(String stringArgument, ReadableMap args, Promise promise) throws JSONException{

    try {
        final JSONObject options = convertMapToJson(args);
        Bundle extras = new Bundle();;
        int LAUNCH_REQUEST = 0;

        if (options.has("extras")) {
            extras = createExtras(options.getJSONArray("extras"));
            Log.d(TAG,"Extras found");
            Log.d(TAG, options.getString("extras"));
        } else {
            extras = new Bundle();
            Log.d(TAG,"No extras");
        }

        if (options.has("launchRequestCode")) {
            LAUNCH_REQUEST = options.getInt("launchRequestCode");
        }

        Intent packageIntent = new Intent(stringArgument);
        Activity activity = getReactApplicationContext().getCurrentActivity();
        activity.startActivityForResult(packageIntent, LAUNCH_REQUEST);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        //TODO: handle exception
        Log.d(TAG, e.toString());
    }
    
}
```