# Call an application from activity

Tags: android-intent, apk, android

I know there are a lot of similar posts like

this: [Launch an application from another application on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872063/android-launch-an-application-from-another-application)

and this: [Launch Activity from another Application Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9839176/launch-activity-from-another-application-android)

but they do not satisfy my question.

**Background:**

I am working on an application where i need to call an application that is already installed in my phone. e.g `Astro Filemanager`

**My Question is:**

How can i call an application that is installed in my phone from my Activity, keeping in mind that i do not have the package name, i have only the application name.

Can i achieve this?

```
If yes then how?

if not then why?
```

I know that i can call another application using the package name, but in my case i do not have the package name, i have only the application name available

**Another Scenario**

Can i save the .apk file of an application in my project folder and call that apk from there?

Comment: Android has some thing called Intents to achieve this.

Comment: I have already mentioned it. please read the question completely. i have mentioned that i have been trying to use intents but passing application name would'nt do anything

Comment: would the application you want to start be the same everytime? If this is the case there are ways to get the package name..

Comment: You have to pass the package name not the application name, a detailed answer will be this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2780102/open-another-application-from-your-own-intent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a method once which returned all installed apps with their package and display name.

```
public static List<PInfo> getInstalledApps(Context context) {
   List<PInfo> result = new ArrayList<PInfo>();        
   List<PackageInfo> packs = context.getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);

    for(int i=0;i<packs.size();i++) {           
       PackageInfo p = packs.get(i);
       PInfo fileInfo = new PInfo();
       fileInfo.appname =  p.applicationInfo.loadLabel(context.getPackageManager()).toString();
       fileInfo.pname = p.packageName;
       fileInfo.versionName = p.versionName;
       fileInfo.versionCode = p.versionCode;
       fileInfo.icon = p.applicationInfo.loadIcon(context.getPackageManager());
       result.add(fileInfo);
    }   
    return result;
}
```

Maybe you could search the package name by the display name and create an intent with that package name.

Comment: It's alot easier to use default pm app to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to start Astro File Manager to pick a file, then you can start

```
final Intent getContent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
//check if there are any app to handle. If not, you must not call startActivity.
if (!getPackageManager.queryIntentActivities(getContent, 0).isEmpty()) {
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT));
}
```

Note if there is an app which has defaults for GET_CONTENt you will not see a chooser. You can force chooser by creating a chooser intent

```
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT), "Pick an app"));
```

Don't forget to check if queryIntentActivities are not empty b

If you just want to start Astro explicitly, you must use it's package name

```
startActivity(getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(ASTRO_PACKAGE));
```

Where ASTRO_PACKAGE can be found as

```
adb shell pm list packages astro
```

Where

- **adb shell** starts next command in adb shell
- **pm** starts package manager app
- **list packages** command of package manager
- **astro** is a filter parameter for *list packages* command