# Launching input method settings activity

Tags: android, ime

I need to launch existing input method settings activity from my app.
For example input method settings activity is com.htc.android.htcime.settings.KeyboardSettings.

How can I launch it?

I tried this [Launch Activity from another Application Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9839176/launch-activity-from-another-application-android), but it doesn't work. I have exception

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write

```
android:exported="true"
```

while declaring  activity in Manifest..

Hope will help you...